# Excel Data Validation - Dont allow Formulas

Tags: excel

Is there any way of using Data Validation to stop someone entering a Formula and only allow text?

I don't want somebody using a formula to search very hidden sheets because they will know the names of these sheets.

I know excel is not secure, but I don't want someone to easily read these sheets with just =SHEET!A1

I have tried custom validation

```
  =ISERROR(FIND("=",A1))
```

but unfortunately I need to allow them to use the = sign

Comment: I'm not sure about data validation but `Worksheet_Change` and `.HasFormula` can erase any formula put into a worksheet. If you are worried about a user disabling events to bypass then you probably need more security than is natively available.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - really simple - create a *Custom* data validation and use formula:  =NOT(ISFORMULA(A1))

No need to over-engineer it with VBA, but of course its easily disabled

Answer (score 0):

No there is not.  The closest you could come would be to write a UDF that detects the presence of a formula; enter that UDF on some cell in the active sheet, and reference that cell in the data validation formula.

However, that would not prevent a user from entering a formula in some other cell, and then copy/paste to the validated cell.  Data validation only checks when a formula is entered directly.  It does not check that pasted data conforms to the rule(s).

Jeeped's suggestion of using worksheet event code would be the way to go.  And you could easily protect the entire sheet from that phenomenon.